# Google MarkerClusterer - change icons dynamically

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to change cluster icons dynamically? The criteria is not the amount of markers in the cluster, but some given values for the data inside the cluster. And I need to update the icons each 10 seconds depending on those data. I havent found any samples for this I am wondering whether its possible or not. I tried following but it dosent have any effect:

```
$.each(global.markersCluster.clusters_, function (index, cluster) {
   cluster.clusterIcon_.index_ = 2;
   cluster.clusterIcon_.url_ = '';

   var eee = '';
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In the [Marker cluster documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering) it shows that you can create a marker cluster like this

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
        {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
}
```

Therefore you can play around with the **markers**. In this case there's a short conditional, bear in mind that the code won't accept anything more complex like for statements, switch cases.

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
        {imagePath: imgPath = (markers < 10) img1 : img2'});
}
```

In that case what I would do would be to encapsulate the markerclusterer creation inside a function and call that every 10 seconds.

```
function updateMarkerClusterer(newIcon, oldMarkerClusterer) {
  var map = oldMarkerClusterer.getMap(),
      markers = oldMarkerClusterer.getMarkers();

  oldMarkerClusterer.clearMarkers();

  var updatedMarkerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
    {imagePath: newIcon});
  }

}
```

In this case you remove the cluster and create it again, there are also the `resetDraw()` and `resetViewport()` methods you can try out.
 Here's the [MarkerClusterer for Google Maps v3](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html) reference for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Setting the icon is not the issue. Every 10 seconds I update data, and I need to be able to update the cluster if needed after setting the icon initially. As you can see in my sample I tried looping the clusters, and setting the icon url. I also tried with imagePath, but same result. The icon dosent change after the 10 seconds.